# Unable to Debug Multi-Threaded Application with gdb

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I am debugging a multi-threaded application with gdb, but when I start the program in gdb I get the warning:

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

I can still debug, but I can't debug anything other than the main thread. I have read forums that suggest installing the packages libthread-db1 and glibc-dbg, but this does not correct the problem for me.

On my machine I have the 3 files `/lib/libthread_db.so.1`, `/lib/.debug/libthread_db-1.0.so`, and `/lib/libthread_db-1.0.so`.  I tried creating symbolic links in `/lib` with the name `libthread_db.so`, one time pointing at the `/lib/libthread_db.so.1` file, and another time pointing at the `/lib/libthread_db-1.0.so` file, and also I created the symbolic link `/lib/.debug/libthread_db.so` pointing to `/lib/.debug/libthread_db-1.0.so`, all with no luck.

In gdb I have tried setting `libthread-db-search-path` to `/lib` (with the symlink once set to `libthread_db.so.1`, and once to `libthread_db-1.0.so`, and also set to `/lib/.debug`.

Any suggestions? I am using Angstrom Linux v2.6.39 for the BeagleBoard-xm.

Comment: Note that I started with a root file system from a 2.6.32 kernel (Angstrom-Beagleboard-demo-image-glibc-ipk-2011.1-beagleboard.rootfs.tar.bz2), and copied the linux source into /usr/src, and cross-compiled a new kernel based on 2.6.39. This is likely the reason for the version mismatch. I have the threading shared object files from the cross compiler, and I tried replacing the existing .so files with the ones from the cross compiler, but it caused make to crash. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi I'm currently having the exact same issue on angstrom running on a beaglebone. Did you ever figure out the solution?

Comment: Also, be sure your version of libpthread is `not stripped`

Answer (score 8):

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library

This means that your `/lib/libthread_db.so.1` does not match your `/lib/libpthread.so.0`. Such mismatch could be the result of you installing different versions of `libc` and `libthread_db` packages, or updating one or the other outside of the package management system. It could also be an error in your packages (i.e. they may not be built correctly).

You should *ignore* `/lib/.debug/*` -- that is *not* the library you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in trying to use

```
set libthread-db-search-path [path]
```

however, it seems you have still not pointed it at a version of libthread_db that is compatible with the pthreads library you're using.

First, check which pthread library you're linked to using ldd:

```
ldd your_executable
```

then make sure the libthread-db-search-path points to a location that has a compatible version of libthread_db with whatever libpthread you're getting. It could be that you're dynamic linker path is getting a different pthread library than you expect.

Comment: This is quite old topic but just a suggestion: instead of `ldd` you can use `readelf`.

Comment: ```compatible version of libthread_db``` How do we find this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your process in **docker container**, please restore your coredump also in **container**!

I add my case and solution here, which may help someone.

The process is deployed to run in docker container, and then I crash it with `kill -3`. The compressed coredump file will be generated according to my settings.

When the coredump file is decompressed from my `Host OS`, then GDB in docker will give WARNING:

```
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
```

And GDB can show nothing useful information.

When the coredump file is decompressed from the `container`, then the above warning is fixed with:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
```

And GDB can successfully show debug information like stack trace.